# how to use case to select sum from table using multiple conditions in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get sum of marks of level 4 and 5 from Results using a phone number as primary key .

The following way is the way it supposed to be but can not work with this i need to use case sql statement  or anothe trick of sql if exists:

```
SELECT
 SUM(marks)
FROM Results 
 WHERE  phone=343435 AND  level='Level 4' AND level='Level  5';
```

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `OR` instead of `AND` like `level='Level 4' OR level='Level  5'`.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(marks)
FROM Results 
WHERE  phone=343435 AND  (level='Level 4' OR level='Level  5');
```

Or you can use an `IN` operator.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(marks)
FROM Results 
WHERE  phone=343435 AND  level IN('Level 4','Level  5');
```

Comment: @UIlas . Thanks . I prefered to use IN(..) at my first time but twice work very fine !

Comment: It's also worth noting that IN is faster than Multiple OR's.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an Or statement instead of and. You are saying the record's level field needs to have a value of 4 AND a value of 5. Instead of, give me rows where the VALUE =4 OR 5

```
SELECT
 SUM(marks)
FROM Results 
 WHERE  phone=343435 AND  (level='Level 4' OR level='Level  5');
```